# Facebook open graph - tagging 'friends' and 'venue' individually

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

i am trying to post a message in facebook through open graph from my php code, following is my php code

```
$params = array('experience'=>$site_url.'comments.php?fb:app_id='.$app_id.'&og:type=parii_apps:experience&og:title=Experience at '.$ven_name.'&og:description='.$content.'&og:image='.$site_url.'venues/original/'.$ven_image.'&venue_id='.$venue_id.'&action=comment&status=venue&status_id='.$venue_id.'&user_id='.$user_id.'&content='.$content.'&act_id='.$act_id,'tags'=>$firend_ids);

$out = $facebook->api( '/'.$fb_user_id.'/app_name:action_type','post', $params);
```

in my facebook posting is use to get as

[Sathia](https://www.facebook.com/sathia.moorthy.739) has shared an experience on "AppName" - with [Ram](https://www.facebook.com/sathia.moorthy.739), [Ganesh](https://www.facebook.com/sathia.moorthy.739) and 4 others.

But i need the post to be as follows

[Sathia](https://www.facebook.com/sathia.moorthy.739) has shared an experience on "AppName" at "Venue Name" - with [Ram](https://www.facebook.com/sathia.moorthy.739), [Ganesh](https://www.facebook.com/sathia.moorthy.739) and 4 others.

I want this venue name to be a tagged(hyperlinked) one as like friends name, but tagged to a Facebook page of the venue so that when any one clicks the venue name link on that post it will gets redirected to the venue's Facebook page.

how to get this, is there any thing i am missing in my php code.